# Clearing out Function Hiding compiler warnings in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, method-hiding

I'm getting "hiding" warnings in my compiler because a class inherits from its parent has the same name but different parameters.

Adding a function that merely pushes out a warning to say that this function does nothing (as is true in the base class, but without the warning) that matches the parameters and name of the base class function to the derived class clears this compiler warning. What are the potential knock-on effects of this on the derived class?

EDIT: Assume that I do not wish them to be able to use the base class function. (Don't ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inability of your users to access the base class function through a derived instance without explicitly writing out `myDerivedObj.Base::foo()`, which they're not likely to do.

Make your function signatures match up, instead, or change the function name.

Comment: I should have been more specific. The base class function does nothing and should really be virtual, but I don't have permissions to change that library. I just need to make sure it's not called.

Comment: @deworde: You can't "make sure it's not called", but providing a hiding definition in a derived class may help.

Answer (score 2):

Redefining the name in the derived class effectively hides the function in the base class. That's what the warning tells you! :-)

It is a warning, because usually this is a mistake. If it is on purpose, that is ok (but very rare).

Answer (score 0):

You need to unhide the base class function in the derived class as:

```
using Base::Function;
```

Example:

```
class Base
{
public:
   void Function(int) { cout << "Function(int)" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   using Base::Function; //NOTE THIS LINE : Unhiding base class function!
   void Function(const char *) { cout << "Function(const char *)" << endl; }
};

Derived d;
d.Function(10); //this calls Base::Function
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/OTBxg

Comment: I should have been more specific. The base class function does nothing and should really be virtual, but I don't have permissions to change that library. I just need to make sure it's not called.

Comment: @deworde: Why don't you post some code so that we could understand your problem a bit better?